# What if North Koreans accidentally shot a South Korean?

Tags: united-states, geopolitics, international

Somebody posted this on Twitter:

If during shooting a North Korean defector, a South Korean soldier is accidentally killed (by N. Koreans), would that start a war?

Comment: It would certainly count as an Act of War in many situations.  The Koreas are technically at war now.  But whether it would cause a resumption of hostilities is entirely speculative and dependent on what the two countries choose to do from there.  There may be a question that could be asked that would work for this site, but this isn't it.  It's really just a call for speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost definitely no given how many border incidents have occurred with casualties on either or both sides even in the recent past.  For example one of the deadlier incidents is the sinking of the ROKS Cheonan in 2010 that resulted in the death of 46 (South Korean) sailors.

Also they are technically already at war, but border incidents are unlikely to escalate to something like Seoul getting shelling into the ground or Pyongyang being level by bombing runs.